# How to cite an article?

Tags: support

While citing references in questions, I paste the web address of a website. But someone usually edits the question where instead of the web address, a word contains the hyperlink to the site. How do I do this?

Comment: Are you just asking how to create a [link](https://example.com) or are you asking about if it's preferred to put the pure URL in the post instead of hiding it behind a link?

Comment: On how to create a link?

Comment: There is [links section](https://politics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#links) in [editing help](https://politics.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to create such links when you write questions or answers.

1. Mark the words you want to turn into a link, and then click on the link-icon (third from the left) in the toolbar above the input box and enter the target URL.
2. Type it in yourself using this syntax: `[words you want to turn into a link](https://example.com)`. This also works in comments, by the way.

You can look up such things in the markdown help. When you write an answer, click on the question mark in the upper right corner of the input box to access it.

Comment: There is [links section](https://politics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#links) in [editing help](https://politics.stackexchange.com/editing-help). Maybe this is worth adding - so that people can find more details here. (Admittedly, the more advanced features - like tooltip text for example - are useful only very rarely.